# How do i remove dash(-) in R?

Tags: r

I'm very new to r. How should I make r read dash(-) or skip it and calculate average of No. of plant(last column).

```
Genotype Rep    No. of plant
184  1   8
7    1   7
98   1   -
101  2   7
X    2   8
62   2   -
24   3   3
30   3   4
78   3   8
119  3   8
```

Comment: You can use the `na.strings="-"` argument in `read.csv` or `read.table`. This will replace the "-" with a missing value (NA).

Comment: @lmo or `fread` ;-)

Comment: Thanks man it worked......

Comment: but I bumped into new problem 
when I write summary code it gives me average but when I write mean code it gives 'NA'

Any idea where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options.

1. You can use `gsub` to convert it to an `NA`. For example `gsub('-', NA, dat$'No. of plant', fixed=TRUE)`. (Use backticks instead of quotes). Then convert the data to numeric using `as.numeric()`
2. You can also specify the NA values when importing your data.

Below is an example:

```
dat=data.frame(Genotype=c(184, 7, 98, 101, 'X'),
           Rep=c(1,1,1,2,2),
           No=c(8,7,'-',7,8))

dat$No <- gsub('-',NA,dat$No,fixed=TRUE)
dat$No <- as.numeric(dat$No)
```

Comment: It's best to perform the action on the "read-in" as this will let R convert the variables to their proper type. If performing your first suggestion, you'd then have to go through the variables and convert them as you point out. This will result in multiple copies and can be a bit of a pain if there are a lot of variables to convert.